# Class 'SourceServer' not found, using steam-condenser libray

Tags: php, class, namespaces, composer-php

I am fairly new at PHP so this might be a stupid question.

I am trying to write a simple website which would be able to display live informations of a Source Server, for that purpose I have installed steam-condenser, a libray enabling queries to the server, trough composer.

I want to instantiate a server object defined in the library, so I require composer autloader, which if I understand correctly would normally load all the classes I would need.

But every time I try to instantiate the object I get a `Class 'SourceServer' not found in [pathofmyphpfile] ...`.

The weird thing is that I am using intelliphense, which is aware of the class because if I type `use S` intelliphense shows SourceServer in the autocompletion menu.

I tried to solve this problem for the whole afternoon, but nothing I tried worked.

As far that I understand it could be linked to composer not generating the autoloader files properly.

Edit : here is my code

index.php :

```
<?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use \SteamCondenser\Servers\SourceServer;

    $server = new SourceServer('serverip', port);

    $server->initialize();
    $server_info = $server->getServerInfo();
    $players = $server_info['numberOfPlayers'];
    $maxplayers = $server_info['maxPlayers'];
    $slot_info = $players . "/" . $maxplayers;
    $server->disconnect();
?>
```

If it helps, index.php is in projet folder>web and all libraries files are in project folder>vendor which has been generated by composer on install.

Comment: its in the following namespace `\SteamCondenser\Servers`

Comment: Trying to use SteamCondenser\Servers\SourceServer does not change anything for me

Comment: show your code, have you even added the autoloader? the docs are thin for that lib, but there is some [tests](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-php/blob/master/tests/SteamCondenser/servers/SourceServerTest.php) which you can see how it ties in.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have edited my post

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried that to no avail

Comment: I have noticed something weird which is probably linked, when installed trough composer, the library composer.json does not contain an autoload section but the samefile from the same version has one on github

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem,

Composer installs steam-condenser v1.3.10 by default, which is a version with a weird composer.json file lacking the "autoload" section, which in turns leads to a bad autoload files generation which do not contain any classes.

You have to install version from the master branch by using `composer require koraktor/steam-condenser:dev-master` and `composer dumpautoload -o` just to be safe to install the latest version.